# (Java Android) No suitable constructor found for type, can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type Information?)

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I have a POJO class that has a many StringRequest function to get a JSON.

So I'm trying to get JSON response from an API and save it to the database, but the problem is sometimes i get the :

> No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class ....Model.TheModel]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?) at [....line 1, column:3]

Here is screenshot of the problem :

[screenshoot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D3iu.png)

here is the fragment of the code :

```
public StringRequest getSales(String siteCode){
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.commit();

StringRequest reqMasterRackCategory = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "The URL",
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                ... (some function to send the response to db )

                }catch (Exception ex){
                    Toast.makeText(context, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        Toast.makeText(context, volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
reqMasterRackCategory.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
    @Override
    public int getCurrentTimeout() {
        return context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.VOLLEY_TIMEOUT_MS); // this return (int) 100000
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
        return context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.VOLLEY_MAX_RETRIES); // this return (int) 50000
    }

    @Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
        Toast.makeText(context,"(Volley)"+error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
    }

});
Log.d(TAG, "getRack: "+reqMasterRackCategory);
return reqMasterRackCategory;
```

}

I browse for the same problem, and it suggest to try make a constructor for the class, but it doesn't solve my problem, i think it's because my class has a lot of StringRequest function inside it.

*Note*: The JSON response for this function was so huge

i'm asking for a solution in this problem, and i appreciate for any comment or solution

Comment: Firstly you should print the exception using `Log.e()` to get more information on the error. Its not very clear what the error is about. Post the stacktrace also in the question.
`Log.e("Error", error);`

Comment: @ping.shantanu i did change it to Log.e() and the response was E/IPE DOWNLOAD: getRack: [ ] http://..... 0xfd121ffe NORMAL null